# Integrating Crashlytics build script with Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, crashlytics

I am trying to integrate Crashlytics with Xamarin.iOS.  I have successfully added a binding and started the logger with my API key.  I'm able to crash the app but no reports are landing on the web dashboard.  When adding Crashlytics to an xcode project it prompts you to add a build phase task to run a script (Which I believe uploads your symbol files to their website).

```
./Crashlytics.framework/run APIKEY
```

After creating a binding of the framework for Xamarin this doesn't work as expected...  I haven't added a build task in Xamarain Studio but running the command from the terminal yeilds:

```
MacBook-Pro:Crashlytics.framework user$ ./run APIKEY
2013-09-04 16:10:49.941 run[9238:707] Crashlytics.framework/run 1.2.3
2013-09-04 16:10:49.943 run[9238:707] 

Crashlytics: Failed to Detect Build Environment

BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR value not found in environment
```

So finally the question:

How do you integrate this build script into the Xamarin environment?  Do I need to copy more assets around to trick the `run` command into thinking all is well?

Comment: When I contacted them a week ago, they said, they do no support Xamarin.iOS apps. I am awaiting a SDK for Xamarin myself. Until then I am using TestFlight SDK 2.0 which supports crash reporing.

Comment: @MohibSheth thanks for the info.  I'll check out TestFlight

Comment: If you're looking for an officially supported crash reporting plugin, Crittercism just released one (Disclaimer: I'm one of the co-founders).  You can download it from the Xamarin store here: http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest versions of Xamarin Studio support Crashlytics out of the box:

[image]

Comment: May I ask you what version do you have? I can not see "Crash Reporting" page in the options. Is it something that is only in the Enterprise version?

Comment: Dmitry must be running 4.1 the pre-release build... It's not in 4.0.13

Comment: I am unable to find this in the latest release on alpha channel as well. Dmitry could you help?

Comment: When it will be announced for public access?

Comment: When it'll be available?

Comment: The above UI is actually built into the current stable release, but its hidden until you manually edit your csproj file. I've turned mine on and its working great. They even inject handling code that serializes your managed exceptions for nice display in the Crashlytics dashboard! Required csproj edits here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/47733/#Comment_47733

Comment: This is now deprecated in the mtouch compiler. You should not use it.

Answer (score 0):

We had been using Crashlytics with our Xamarin project. But, [it seems with Xamarin.iOS 8.6 and/or Xamarin Studio 5.7 it is no longer supported, and the Crashlytics APIs have changed.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/91986#Comment_91986)

[Here are the steps I used.](http://benbutzer.com/blog/?p=298)

1. In the Xamarin Studio , go to the touch container and add the Crashlytics API key in the **Build -> Crash** reporting section. Build and run that app. The evidence suggests that is enough to get data sent to Crashlytics. I saw that it knew about older versions of the app I had built and ran weeks ago with the API key already in.
2. Go to Xcode and create a new project with the same name as the Xamarin project, `com.{company}.{appname}`. (You probably need to have that profile downloaded.) I did it in Swift by the way with no issues.
3. Go to crashlytics.com com and go to **settings -> Apps** (or https://www.crashlytics.com/onboard)
4. You will get an app to download and run. The app walks through the steps of adding

   - A build phase run script
   - Code to the application main `Crashlytics.startWithAPIKey(“nnnn”)`
5. Run your Xcode version of the app

The Crashlytics web page popped up immediately.

Comment: Note that Crashlytics is being replaced by Firebase.